# Can anyone help me to understand how Load file in WP8 (PickSingleFileAndContinue) work?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get my program to read a simple text file, but after 12+ hours of reading his example, I am getting a little frustrated. The `PickSingleFileAsync` for **Windows app is so easy to understand**, but cannot be used for WP8 :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994.aspx

Edit: Ok, my main problem is this: Inside the ContinuationManager, after I choose a file my fileOpenPickerPage is null, and I do not know why.

I have downloaded the code, and implemented the ContinuationManager class in my program. I have the SuspensionManager help class in my code.
Here is my code:

ContinuationManager (As the example)

SuspensionManager (Generated by Visual Basic)

App.xaml.cs file: The Frame is the problem here I think.

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    public ContinuationManager continuationManager { get; private set; }
#endif

Some code..............................

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string test = Convert.ToString (e);

        base.OnActivated(e);

        continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();
        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
        var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
        if (continuationEventArgs != null)
        {
            Frame scenarioFrame = MainPage.Current.FindName("ScenarioFrame") as Frame;
            if (scenarioFrame != null)
            {
                MessageDialog msg2 = new MessageDialog("scenarioFrame is\n" + Convert.ToString(rootFrame.Content));
                await msg2.ShowAsync();
                // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation
                continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, scenarioFrame);
            }
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
#endif
```

LoadSavePage (Page where I want to push a button and read/load a file.

```
public sealed partial class LoadSavePage : Page, IFileOpenPickerContinuable
{
    .......Some Code............

    private void LoadWeapons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
    }
```

Comment: [The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below :

**Add this two lines in `LoadWeapons_Click` after `openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();`.**

**Add `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;` namespace to access CoreApplicationView.**

```
CoreApplicationView view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
view.Activated += viewActivated;
```

Edit :

```
private void LoadWeapons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
    openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();

    CoreApplicationView view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
    view.Activated += viewActivated;
}
```

**And finally copy below handler in your code.**

```
private async void viewActivated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
{
    try
    {
        FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
        if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;
            view.Activated -= viewActivated;

            if (args.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s)
                foreach (StorageFile file in args.Files)
                {               
                    // Launch file.
                    bool filelaunch = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```